# SUMIF(S) with a SUMIF(S) criteria

Tags: excel

I have the following Excel spreadsheet:

```
        A          B               C         D        E        F         G
1              Budget Profit    1.Sales  2.Sale   3.sale      
2   Product A     50              500       600       0      Product A   100
3   Product A     50                0       400       0      Product B   90  
4   Prodcut A     20                0         0       0      Product C   180
5   Product B     90              800         0       500
6   Product C     90                0         0       400
7   Product C     90              300       750       200
```

In **Column A** different products are listed. *It can happen that the same products appear several times in the list.* 
In **Column B** you can find the budgeted profit for each product and in **Columns C:E** the different sales of each product.

In **Column G** I want to achieve now that the sum of each product is calculated but only if the sum of the sales (Columns C:E) is >0 or - in other words - if there is any sales for the product the profit should be summed up.

So far I came up with something like this:

```
=SUMIFS($B$2:$B$7;$A$2:$A$7;F2;$C$2:$E$7;">"&0)
```

However, this formula does not seem to work. I get an #VALULE! error.

Do you have any idea how I could make this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SUMIFS() ranges need to be the same size, And since you want OR Not AND You will need to use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT($B$2:$B$7*(($C$2:$C$7>0)+($D$2:$D$7>0)+($E$2:$E$7>0)>0)*($A$2:$A$7=F2))
```

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks for the answer. It works perfectly. How would you actually change this formula if you want to have all formulas for example >15. I tried to go with SUMPRODUCT($B$2:$B$7*(($C$2:$C$7>15)+($D$2:$D$7>15)+($E$2:$E$7>15)>15)*($A$2:$A$7=F2)) but it gives me a 0 as result. Theoretically it should give me the same result as the formula with >0. Do you know where my mistake is?

Comment: Change the last `>15` back to `>0`